# Google sign-in prompt is not shown again after user closes the prompt only once

Tags: javascript, google-signin, google-identity

I am trying to gapi to Google Identity Services in js client-side [Google-SignIn](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web).

SignIn Prompt is working with `google.accounts.id.prompt()` after

```
   google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
      callback: handleCredentialResponse
    });
```

But if user closes prompt manually even if it is only once, prompt doesn't pop up again even the page is refreshed. Probably it is (suppressed_by_user). Is there a way to increase this cancel_limit number ?

Comment: I think you can use cancel_on_tap_outside field to do it.

Comment: @KavinduChathuranga I guess it's only to handle if a user clicks outside the prompt. My question is about, when the user clicks close button on prompt. It just never shows up again even after the site is closed and reopened after

Comment: This is due to the One-Tap exponential cool-down. (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/features#exponential_cool-down) It should show up again after 2 hours. The time period increases if the user closes it consecutively

Answer (score 0):

The Exponential cool-down behavior is explained here-

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/features#exponential_cool-down

> If the user closes the One Tap prompt manually, the One Tap prompt is
> suppressed. A user closes One Tap when they tap Close close in the
> top-right corner of the prompt. One Tap won't display in the same
> browser or the last website visited for a period of time.

If you want to enable the Sign in pop-up again, delete the `g_state` cookie

[image]

Developer Tools -> Application -> Cookies -> [Your website]